# Python, Return from a function fails, stuck in While Loop

Tags: python, while-loop

I am new to python and coding and for a school project I have to print a simple receipt. I am using a few functions and one of them, which asks for the prices of the purchased items, uses a While Not Loop. The input loops until the user enters '0'.

The problem is that if I input a purchased item price with three or more decimal places (e.g 19.999). When they enter 0 after this incorrect input, the Return command seems to get stuck in the While Not Loop. When the code gets to the Return command, execution jumps to the While Not Loop and back again, then half way through the While Not Loop to 'prices = str(prices)' and continues normally. The result is that we cannot exit the program the intended way, with a '0'.

Here is the function.

```
def shop_list(): #this definition asks for the prices of the items, adds the input to a list and loops, until 0 is entered, which stops the loop.
    while True:
        try:
            prices = float(input("Please input a value. Enter 0 to print receipt: ")) # the input that allows the customer to enter their prices
            zero_check.append(prices)
            if prices == 0:
                if len(zero_check) == 1:
                    if zero_check[0] == 0:
                        exit_ask()
                    else:
                        'do nothing' #this is a place holder line, something must be here but we dont need anything here
                else:
                    'do nothing'
            else:
                'do nothing'
        except ValueError: #if the input creates an error, do the below
            print("\nERROR, please enter a valid number.\n") #this error message will come up if you input anything other than a number
            continue #loops the back to the 'try'
        else:
            break #breaks the While True loop

    if prices != 0: 
        number = None
        while not number:
            prices = str(prices) #converting the price to a string so we can split it
            string_number = prices.split(".") #splitting the price at the decimal point
            if len(string_number[1]) > 2: #if there is more than two decimal points, print an error
                print ("\nERROR: Too many decimal places!\n")
                prices = float(prices)
                shop_list()
            else:
                number = float(prices)

            prices = str(prices)
            price_lnth = len(prices)

            if price_lnth > 15:
                print ('\nERROR, too many numbers.\n')
                shop_list()
            else:
                prices = float(prices)

            if prices > 0: #if the input was valid then this will run
                shopplist.append(prices) #this is what adds a price into a list
                shop_list() # loops back to the start of this definition              
            elif prices < 0:
                print('\nERROR, no negative numbers.\n')
                shop_list() # loops back to the start of this definition   

    else:
        'do nothing'
    return
```

Comment: first of all, indent your code properly

Comment: You don't need the `else: 'do nothing'` phrases. There is nothing wrong with having an `if` with no `else`.

Comment: One advantage may be that the structure is unambiguous, so that indenting in the editor doesn't by accident put a following `else:` at the wrong level. But I think the added clutter is not worth it. An alternative when you sometimes do need a line that does nothing is `pass`.

Answer (score 0):

When there is an error (and in the normal logic too), you call `shop_list()` recursively. When you then enter 0, this second invocation returns, but the original one carries on where it was. I suggest working with loops only, not recursion, or perhaps only recursion (but remember that recursion will eat stack space).

Comment: Thank you very much for your response! Do you have a suggestion on how to remove recursion and rely on loops only? I am new to coding and the things that are obvious to others are not obvious to me. Any feedback is appreciated!